# PHPMailer sets the From same as the smtp username

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer library to send SMTP email for booking enquiry.  (Note: The same problem I was facing in PHP Pear Mail library as well).

I set the email from as below

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                 // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'gmail.owner@gmail.com';      // SMTP username
$mail->Port = 465;               // TCP port to connect to
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Password = 'xxxx';
$mail->setFrom(mark.antony@example.com, Mark Antony);
$mail->replyTo(mark.antony@example.com, Mark Antony); 
$mail->addAddress(gmail.owner@gmail.com, Gmail Owner);
$mail->Subject = $whatever subject;
$mail->Body    = $whatever html;
```

The problem is after sending email in the received mailbox I see the `From:` is the same as `To:` (Or same as the gmail/smtp username).
I have fixed the problem on reply to by setting `replyTo` value.

Is there anyway I can fix this? Or is that how it suppose to be?

Comment: Does your actual code miss out all of the quotes in the last 3 lines?

Comment: @NigelRen Sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Google does not allow you to set arbitrary *from* addresses, because doing so is usually forgery. If you try to, gmail will ignore it and substitute your `Username` address, which is what you're seeing.

There is one exception to this: you can set up additional aliases in your gmail settings (which you need to verify), and once you've done that you can use those addresses as *from* addresses.

If you're using this for a contact form (as it sounds like you are), setting to and from to your own address, and the submitter as a reply-to is the correct way to go, as [the PHPMailer contact form example demonstrates](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).